# Ansible playbook to insert a line if specific line not present

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to modify a logrotate file on multiple servers. When the line "noolddir" is not present in a block in the file, the line should be added.
I wrote this playbook:

```yaml
- name: Update logrotate files on servers
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: change myapplication
    ansible.builtin.replace:
      path: /etc/logrotate.d/myapplication
      regexp:  '(?:noolddir\n)?(rotate 30)$'
      replace: '    noolddir\n\1'
```

but, it is not working.
The logrotate file I need to edit looks like this:

```
/opt/appvendor/log//myapplication_*.log {
    daily
    rotate 30
    compress
    missingok
    notifempty
    su root appvendor
    dateext
    postrotate
        /bin/systemctl reload httpd.service > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
    endscript
    }

/opt/otherapplication/instances/*/*/otherapplication/logs/*.log
/opt/otherapplication/instances/*/somefolder/*/*/logs/*.log {
    daily
    noolddir
    rotate 30
    compress
    missingok
    notifempty
    copytruncate
    su root appvendor
}
```

The result should be:

```
/opt/appvendor/log//myapplication_*.log {
    daily
    noolddir
    rotate 30
    compress
    missingok
    notifempty
    su root appvendor
    dateext
    postrotate
        /bin/systemctl reload httpd.service > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
    endscript
    }

/opt/otherapplication/instances/*/*/otherapplication/logs/*.log
/opt/otherapplication/instances/*/somefolder/*/*/logs/*.log {
    daily
    noolddir
    rotate 30
    compress
    missingok
    notifempty
    copytruncate
    su root appvendor
}
```

However when I run the playbook, nothing is changed.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer isn't the most optimal one, but I hope it helps.
The Idea is to search for both `rotate 30` and `noolddir\n    rotate 30` and replace them.
I am not experienced with regex, but tried my best, see https://regex101.com/r/YPnlM3/1.
That means for the playbook to do its job, every block in file should have `rotate 30`

```yaml
- name: Update logrotate files on servers
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: change myapplication
    ansible.builtin.replace:
      path: /etc/logrotate.d/myapplication
      regexp:  'noolddir\n.*rotate 30$|\.*rotate 30$'
      replace: 'noolddir\n    rotate 30'
```